# Class file cannot be found

Tags: java, android, build

I'm working on an app and a while ago it was still working and it was building just fine, but after a few minutes of coding, I tried to build again then an error showed up

> " error: cannot access zzbck class file for
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbck not found "

```
package com.lrtapp.ardentmap;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.Task;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "map is ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady: map is ready");
        mMap = googleMap;

        if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
            getDeviceLocation();

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                return;
            }
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);

            init();
        }
    }

    private static final String TAG = "MapActivity";

    private static final String FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
    private static final String COURSE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
    private static final float DEFAULT_ZOOM = 15f;

    //widgets
    private EditText mSearchText;
    private ImageView mGps;

    //vars

    private boolean mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        mSearchText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_search);
        mGps = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ic_gps);

        getLocationPermission();

    }

    private void init(){
        Log.d(TAG, "init: Initializing");

        mSearchText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH
                        || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
                        ||  keyEvent.getAction() == keyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                        || keyEvent.getAction() == keyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){

                    //execute method for searching
                    geoLocate();

                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        mGps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: clicked gps icon");
                getDeviceLocation();

            }
        });

        hideSoftKeyboard();
    }

    private void geoLocate(){
        Log.d(TAG, "geoLocate: geolocating");

        String searchString = mSearchText.getText().toString();

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MapActivity.this);
        List<Address> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try{
            list = geocoder.getFromLocationName(searchString, 1);
        }catch(IOException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "geoLocate: IOException" + e.getMessage());
        }
        if(list.size() > 0){
            Address address = list.get(0);

            Log.d(TAG, "GeoLocate: found a Location: " +address.toString());

           // Toast.makeText(this, address.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT()).show();

            moveCamera(new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM,
                    address.getAddressLine(0));
        }
    }

    private void getDeviceLocation(){
        Log.d(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: getting the device's current location.");

        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        try {
            if (mLocationPermissionGranted){

                final com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task location = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
                location.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            Log.d(TAG, "Found Location");
                            Location currentLocation = (Location) task.getResult();

                                moveCamera(new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude()),
                                        DEFAULT_ZOOM,
                                        "My Location");

                        }else{
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: current Location is null");
                            Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "unable to get current location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }catch (SecurityException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: SecurityException: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void moveCamera(LatLng latLng, float zoom, String title){
        Log.d(TAG, "moving the camera to: lat: " + latLng.latitude + ", lng: " +latLng.longitude);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,zoom));

        if(!title.equals("My Location")){
            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLng)
                    .title(title);

            mMap.addMarker(options);
        }
        hideSoftKeyboard();

    }

    private void initMap(){
        Log.d(TAG, "initMap: initializing map");
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapActivity.this);
    }

    private void getLocationPermission(){
        Log.d(TAG, "getLocationPermission: getting location permissions");
        String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(), FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(), COURSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
            initMap();

        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }

        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: called.");
        mLocationPermissionGranted = false;

        switch (requestCode){
            case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:{
                if(grantResults.length > 0){
                    for(int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++){
                        if(grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                            mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
                            Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission failed.");
                            return;
                        }
                    }

                    mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
                    Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission granted.");
                    //initializing map
                    initMap();

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void hideSoftKeyboard(){
        this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    }

}
```

your help will be very appreciated! thanks!

Comment: can you post build.gradle

Comment: alright, here ya go.

Comment: please edit your question add build.gradle there

Comment: i just posted it, im kinda new here im so sorry.